# Magento "left" reference element xml layout problem

Tags: layout, magento-1, xml, local.xml

I have been trying to solve the issue for past few days with no luck.

The left sidebar is missing from all of the 2column-left pages. It worries me especially when it comes to customer account as the customer account navigation is missing too.

Here is my `page.xml` file:

```
    <layout version="0.1.0">
<!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->

    <default translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
        
        
        <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/menu.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>

            <block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>

            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>

            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="after_body_start" as="after_body_start" translate="label">
            <label>Page Top</label>
        </block>

        <block type="page/html_notices" name="global_notices" as="global_notices" template="page/html/notices.phtml" />

        <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
            <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Header</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="page/html_welcome" name="welcome" as="welcome"/>
        </block>

        <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="left" as="left" translate="label">
            <label>Left Column</label>
        </block>

        <block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
        <block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
            <label>Main Content Area</label>
        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="right" as="right" translate="label">
            <label>Right Column</label>
        </block>

        <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Footer</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="before_body_end" as="before_body_end" translate="label">
            <label>Page Bottom</label>
            <block type="page/html_cookieNotice" name="global_cookie_notice" as ="global_cookie_notice" template="page/html/cookienotice.phtml" before="-" />
        </block>
    </block>
    
    <block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler"/>
    
    </default>

    <print translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages (Print Version)</label>
    <!-- Mage_Page -->
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/print.phtml">
        
            <block type="core/text_list" name="left" as="left" translate="label">
            <label>Left Column</label>
        </block>

        <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>

            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>

            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>

        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
            <label>Main Content Area</label>
        </block>
        
        

    </block>
    </print>

     <!-- Custom page layout handles -->
    <page_empty translate="label">
    <label>All Empty Layout Pages</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/empty.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>
    </page_empty>

    <page_one_column translate="label">
    <label>All One-Column Layout Pages</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>
    </page_one_column>

 

    <page_two_columns_right translate="label">
    <label>All Two-Column Layout Pages (Right Column)</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>
    </page_two_columns_right>

    <page_two_columns_left translate="label">
    <label>All Two-Column Layout Pages (left Column)</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
            <action method="setLayoutCode"><name>two_columns_left</name></action>
    </reference>
    </page_two_columns_left>

    <page_three_columns translate="label">
    <label>All Three-Column Layout Pages</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>
    </page_three_columns>

</layout>
```

Here is my `local.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
       <!-- Adding JS / CSS -->
       
       <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/bootstrap.js</name>
            <params/>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/bootstrap-validator/validator.js</name>
            <params/>
        </action>
    </reference>
    
     <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/jquery.slicknav.js</name>
            <params/>
        </action>
    </reference>
    
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js</name>
            <params/>
        </action>
    </reference>
    
     <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/jquery.cookiebar.js</name>
            <params/>
        </action>
    </reference>
    
     <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>js/ie6.js</name>
            <params/>
        </action>
    </reference>
    
      
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/global/global.js</name>
            <params/>
        </action>
    </reference>
    
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/vamp.css</name>
            <params/>
        </action>
    </reference>
    
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/vamp-merge.css</name>
            <params/>
        </action>
    </reference>
    
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/flexslider.css</name>
            <params/>
        </action>
    </reference>
    
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/slicknav.css</name>
            <params/>
        </action>
    </reference>
    
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/jquery.cookiebar.css</name>
            <params/>
        </action>
    </reference>
    
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <if>lt IE 9</if>
        </action>
    </reference>

       <!-- Top Cart -->
       
      <reference name="left">
          
      </reference>
      <reference name="right">
     <remove name="cart_sidebar" />
      </reference>
      
      <reference name="header">
     <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="topCart" template="checkout/cart/top_cart.phtml" before="-">
        <action method="addItemRender">
           <type>simple</type>
           <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block>
           <template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="addItemRender">
           <type>grouped</type>
           <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block>
           <template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="addItemRender">
           <type>configurable</type>
           <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block>
           <template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template>
        </action>
     </block>
      </reference>
      
      <reference name="special_offers">
     <block type="catalog/product_list" name="special_offers_block" template="catalog/product/home-products-slider.phtml">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
           <type>bundle</type>
           <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
           <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
        </action>
     </block>
      </reference>
      
    </default>
    
    <!-- 404 Breadcrumbs -->
    
    <cms_index_noroute>
       <reference name="breadcrumbs">
       <action method="addCrumb">
           <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
           <crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>/home</link></crumbInfo>
       </action>
       <action method="addCrumb">
           <crumbName>404 Page Not Found</crumbName>
           <crumbInfo><label>404 Page Not Found</label><title>404 Page Not Found</title></crumbInfo>
       </action>
       </reference>
   </cms_index_noroute>
   
   <catalog_product_view>
      <reference name="content">
     <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
           <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
              <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                 <label>Review Form Fields Before</label>
                 <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
                 <action method="setElementClass"><value>rewards</value></action>
              </block>
           </block>
        </block>
     </reference>
      </reference>
   </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Here is my `customer.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <default>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
    </default>

<!--
Load this update on every page when customer is logged in
-->

    <customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
    </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>

<!--
Load this update on every page when customer is logged out
-->

    <customer_logged_out>
    <!---<reference name="right">
        <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_mini_login" before="-" template="customer/form/mini.login.phtml"/>
    </reference>-->
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
    </reference>
    <remove name="reorder"></remove>
    </customer_logged_out>

<!--
Layout for customer login page
-->

    <customer_account_login translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Login Form</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml" />
    </reference>
    </customer_account_login>

<!--
Layout for customer log out page
-->

    <customer_account_logoutsuccess translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Logout Success</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="customer_logout" template="customer/logout.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    </customer_account_logoutsuccess>

<!--
New customer registration
-->

    <customer_account_create translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Registration Form</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                <label>Form Fields Before</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
    </customer_account_create>

    <customer_account_forgotpassword translate="label">
    <label>Customer Forgot Password Form</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Forgot Your Password</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Password forgotten</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <!--<block type="core/template" name="forgotPassword" template="customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml"/>-->
        <block type="customer/account_forgotpassword" name="forgotPassword" template="customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml" />
    </reference>
    </customer_account_forgotpassword>

    <customer_account_changeforgotten translate="label">
    <label>Reset a Password</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/account_changeforgotten" name="changeForgottenPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    </customer_account_changeforgotten>

    <customer_account_confirmation>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Send confirmation link</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="accountConfirmation" template="customer/form/confirmation.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    </customer_account_confirmation>

    <customer_account_edit translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Edit Form</label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Edit Account Info</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="customer/form_edit" name="customer_edit" template="customer/form/edit.phtml"/>
    </reference>

    <reference name="left">
      <action method="unsetChild"><name>left.permanent.callout</name></action>
    </reference>
    </customer_account_edit>

<!--
Customer account pages, rendered for all tabs in dashboard
-->

    <customer_account translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account (All Pages)</label>
    <!--remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
    <remove name="sale.reorder.sidebar"/-->
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="content">
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="my.account.wrapper" translate="label">
            <label>My Account Wrapper</label>
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>my-account</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

    <reference name="left">
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
        </block>
        <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
        <remove name="tags_popular"/>

    </reference>
    </customer_account>

<!--
Customer account home dashboard layout
-->

    <customer_account_index translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account Dashboard</label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="customer/account_dashboard" name="customer_account_dashboard" template="customer/account/dashboard.phtml">
            <block type="customer/account_dashboard_hello" name="customer_account_dashboard_hello" as="hello" template="customer/account/dashboard/hello.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="customer_account_dashboard_top" as="top" />
            <block type="customer/account_dashboard_info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml"/>
            <block type="customer/account_dashboard_newsletter" name="customer_account_dashboard_newsletter" as="newsletter" template="customer/account/dashboard/newsletter.phtml"/>
            <block type="customer/account_dashboard_address" name="customer_account_dashboard_address" as="address" template="customer/account/dashboard/address.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>

    </customer_account_index>

<!--
Customer account address book
-->

    <customer_address_index translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account Address Book</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="customer/address_book" name="address_book" template="customer/address/book.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    </customer_address_index>

<!--
Customer account address edit page
-->

    <customer_address_form translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account Address Edit Form</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="customer/address_edit" name="customer_address_edit" template="customer/address/edit.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    </customer_address_form>

</layout>
```

This is my `2column-left.phtml` file:

```
<?php ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>

    <div class="container b30 t30">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>

    <div class="row">
        <aside class="col-md-3">
        
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
        
        </aside>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            
            <?php

                    $yourUrlKey = 'tpd';
                    $yourUrlKey2 = 'tdp-faq';
                    $cmsPageUrlKey = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
                    
                    if($yourUrlKey == $cmsPageUrlKey || $yourUrlKey2 == $cmsPageUrlKey) { ?>
                    
                    <div class="three-buttons mB20">
                            <a class="button green mR20" href="/safety-data/">Safety Data</a> <a class="button green mR20 tpd" href="/tpd/">TOBACCO PRODUCTS DIRECTIVE</a> <a class="button green mR20 faq" href="/tdp-faq/">FAQs</a> <a class="button green" target="_blank" href="https://www.domain.co.uk/new_order_form.xlsx">Download Our Order Form</a>
                        </div>
                    
                    <?php } ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I have no idea how to solve the issue. In `customer.xml` when I change the customer account from `reference name="left"` to `reference name="content"` it is being displayed in the content column.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please post code specific to your problem.

Comment: What do you mean by code specific? I want the customer account navigation to be on on the left but for some reason it is not displaying, when I changed the reference to "content" it works. Really struggling...

Comment: is there any log in var/log ?

Comment: `page.xml , customer.xml and 2column-left.phtml` all are default files or you have changed anything ?

Comment: Also, I am not sure is these are the original files as I have only took over from someone else

Comment: `<layout version="0.1.0">` is not there for  `customer.xml`

Comment: can you verify is it missing from code as well or you missed here only ?

Comment: Ah, sory I just missed it here, layout version="0.1.0" is in the customer.xml file.

Comment: okay. you have so many `Warning: simplexml_load_string()` due to incorrect xml.  the quick track is rename your `customer.xml` to `customer.xml.bk` from your active theme.  magento will load it from base theme. check and post your result here

Comment: In the account, there is nothing now, just a blank empty page with header and footer only.

Comment: you have your custom theme ?

Comment: The application is using boilerplate

Comment: <reference name="left">
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
When I change this name to "content" it is beeing displayed so I presume it has to be something with the "left" reference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found what the problem was. I only took over from someone else and only getting my head around the system.

The problem was, there was a

```
<layout version="1.0">
<default><remove name="left"/></default>
```

element in one of the custom modules written by someone. Removing the

```
<remove name="left"/>
```

fixed my problem.

Comment: ahhhhhh............

Comment: great finally you did it

Comment: Yes, finally... Took me hours to find it and it was hidden in one of the custom modules... Thanks for your interest!